# When does Symfony call the container setter for a controller

Tags: symfony, controller, kernel

I followed https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/index.html
to get a deeper understanding of the symfony components. Sadly the tutorial doesn't go deep enough.

By the end of the tutorial they initiate a container in the index.php and make the framework class known to the container, then call the handle method of the httpkernel to create the controller and get the response.

My question is, how can i call the setter of my controller to make the container known to my controller without extending/overwriting the httpkernel or the controller resolver?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The official way to do it is to inject the container inside the ControllerResolver when the controller is instantiated , https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php#L88

Comment: Thank you, i was confused by the fact that in symfony standard edition they extended the controller resolver but kept the same class name. I just extended my resolver and things are working now!